# How to assign environment variable from bash command

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a config file holding all my environment variables and instead of manually assigning each environment variable, i want to read from my file using bash

```
name: Integration 
on: [push]
jobs:
  tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    services:
      mysql:
        image: mysql:8
        env:
          MYSQL_DATABASE: $(value from bash script)
```

All the guides i've seen only show how to use predefined environment variables and none using dynamic values

Comment: You can use repository secrets. I'm not sure what do you mean to add environment variables using bash?

Comment: say in my example, i just want to assign a  value to the MYSQL_DATABASE env variable with output of bash command.  repository secrets in my case are overkill

Comment: Have you tried using SET in linux command? export MYSQL_DATBASE=$database_name ?

Comment: Take a look here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1015508

Comment: [I don't think you can call environment variables on job level](https://github.community/t/workflow-environment-variables-in-services/17494). What you can do is set up the SQL service on step level using this [action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-mysql). This way, you will be able to [assign your env vars from a shell script](https://github.community/t/how-to-set-action-env-variables-within-a-shell-script/18425/5) a step earlier and use it on your SQL service step.

Comment: You could also use the Github API to add a secret to the repo in your workflow and access it on another step with `${{secrets.MYSQL_DATABASE}}`, then remove this secret on the last step using the Github API again.

Comment: That's what I meant in the first place by using repository secrets. Basically, that's how I deploy GitHub Pages React Application.